# Error installing Ruby on Mac OSX 10.8.3 - Error running 'make -j2'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to install Ruby 2.0.0 on Mac OS X.  I am using Homebrew, RVM and I have Xcode 4.6.1 installed along with the command line tools.  When I run 'rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p0' I ge the following:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary                rubies.
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Already up-to-date.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/jcanipar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0, this may take     a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #downloading ruby-2.0.0-p0, this may take a while depending on your     connection...
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #extracted to /Users/jcanipar/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0 (already extracted)
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #configuring.....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #compiling......................................................................................
Error running 'make -j2',
please read /Users/jcanipar/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

The make.log file has the following:

```
[2013-04-07 00:08:20] make
CC = /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2
LD = ld
LDSHARED = /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 -dynamiclib
CFLAGS = -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=write-strings -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=shorten-64-to-32 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration   -fno-common -pipe 
XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
CPPFLAGS = -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include -I/usr/local/opt/libxslt/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin12.3.0 -I./include -I.
DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libxslt/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib  -install_name /Users/jcanipar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/libruby.2.0.0.dylib -current_version 2.0.0 -compatibility_version 2.0.0  -fstack-protector -Wl,-u,_objc_msgSend  -fstack-protector -Wl,-u,_objc_msgSend  
SOLIBS = 
compiling main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling dmyencoding.c
compiling version.c
compiling miniprelude.c
compiling array.c
compiling bignum.c
compiling class.c
compiling compar.c
compiling complex.c
compiling dir.c
compiling dln_find.c
compiling enum.c
compiling enumerator.c
compiling error.c
compiling eval.c
compiling load.c
compiling proc.c
compiling file.c
compiling gc.c
compiling hash.c
compiling inits.c
compiling io.c
compiling marshal.c
compiling math.c
compiling node.c
compiling numeric.c
compiling object.c
compiling pack.c
compiling parse.c
compiling process.c
compiling random.c
compiling range.c
compiling rational.c
compiling re.c
compiling regcomp.c
compiling regenc.c
compiling regerror.c
compiling regexec.c
compiling regparse.c
compiling regsyntax.c
compiling ruby.c
compiling safe.c
compiling signal.c
compiling sprintf.c
compiling st.c
compiling strftime.c
compiling string.c
compiling struct.c
compiling time.c
time.c: In function ‘localtimew’:
time.c:1503: warning: ‘tm.tm_isdst’ may be used uninitialized in this function
time.c:1503: note: ‘tm.tm_isdst’ was declared here
compiling transcode.c
compiling util.c
compiling variable.c
compiling compile.c
compiling debug.c
compiling iseq.c
compiling vm.c
compiling vm_dump.c
compiling vm_backtrace.c
compiling vm_trace.c
compiling thread.c
compiling cont.c
compiling ./enc/ascii.c
compiling ./enc/us_ascii.c
compiling ./enc/unicode.c
compiling ./enc/utf_8.c
compiling newline.c
compiling ./missing/setproctitle.c
compiling dln.c
compiling encoding.c
compiling dmyversion.c
linking miniruby
ld: can't map file, errno=22 for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [miniruby] Error 1
```

I am completely stumped.  I've read a lot of stuff on here, but nothing has helped.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `rvm requirements` will tell you what you need to install.  `rvm requirements run` will install all everything you need, not only for MRI but jRuby and perhaps a couple other things.  It's a bit of overkill, so you can manually install the packages listed by `rvm requirements` that you need, or not think about it and install them all.

Comment: Running `rvm requirements` tells me `Already up to date`